# Issue with bubble sorting

Tags: python, algorithm, bubble-sort

SO I decided to create a bubble algorithm in Python. The thing is that it works for some numbers,  but it doesn't work for others. Can anyone help:

```
def sort(number):
    to_sort = list(str(number))
    sorted_list = sorted(to_sort)
    print(sorted_list)
    i = 0
    while True:
        if to_sort == sorted_list:
            print(f"Sorted {number} to {''.join(to_sort)}" )
            break
        first_index = to_sort[i]
        try:
            second_index = to_sort[i+1]
        except IndexError:
            i = 0
        if first_index < second_index:
            i += 1
            print(to_sort)
            continue
        elif first_index > second_index:
            print(f"switching {to_sort[i+1]} to {first_index}")
            to_sort[i+1] = first_index
            print(to_sort)
            print(f"Switching {to_sort[i]} to {second_index}")
            to_sort[i] = second_index
            print(to_sort)
            i += 1
            continue

sort(49304)
```

It works for 51428 but not 49304. Anyone know why?

Comment: I think that when you catch the exception you should restart your loop. You need i = 0; continue. Otherwise your ‘index’ variables don’t get reset.

Comment: You say that "It works for 51428 but not 49304". What is your result when you try it on 49304?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fatal flaw is in your loop reset (to 0), combined with your disconnected swapping logic.

```
    first_index = to_sort[i]
    try:
        second_index = to_sort[i+1]
    except IndexError:
        i = 0
    ...
    elif first_index > second_index:
        ...
        to_sort[i] = second_index
```

In the case of running off the end of the list, `second_index` now has the wrong value: it's the *previous* value, since you never reset it after looping `i` back to 0.

(1) Fix your immediate problem by inserting that reset:

```
    except IndexError:
        i = 0
        second_index = to_sort[0]
```

(2) Research existing bubble sorts.  Among other things, make your exchange simpler.

```
    to_sort[i], to_sort[i+1] = to_sort[i+1], to_sort[i]
```

Control `i` so that it doesn't go out of bounds.  Note that you don't have to really worry about swapping the last element with the first: a bubble sort doesn't skip ends like that.